# nomogram() of rms not working in a function

Tags: r, rms

I am trying to make following function work but it is giving errors:

```
> mynomogram
function(sfstr, mydf){
        sf = as.formula(sfstr)
        library(rms)
        mod = ols(sf, mydf)
        dd = datadist(mydf)
        options(datadist='dd')
        plot(nomogram(mod))
}
> 
> mynomogram('mpg~disp+hp+cyl', mtcars)
Error in value.chk(at, i, NA, -nint, Limval, type.range = "full") : 
  variable disp does not have limits defined by datadist
> 
> mynomogram('mpg~disp+hp+cyl', mtcars)
Error in Design(X) : dataset dd not found for options(datadist=)
```

Where is the error and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I needed to keep dd = datadist(mydf) and options(datadist='dd') in global environment. Then it works.

Comment: The second question is not justified since I am converting string to a formula in the function using as.formula.

Comment: @42- please be kind

Comment: @JesseKnight : Kindly explain your comment.

Comment: Another user "42-" previously had a comment on here that was a bit rude. I don't remember what it was, but he's deleted it now. I will delete my comments here too if you like.

Comment: No need. Thanks for explaining. Let this info be here for others to benefit.

Answer (score 4):

use dd <<- datadist(mydf)

Comment: didn't work for me :-/  but rnso suggestions in the comments about global environment worked